# Disable microphone button in UITextField keyboard

Tags: ios, keyboard, uitextfield, uitextinputtraits

I have a UITextField, and the keyboard shows a mic button, which I'd like to disable. I'm especially concerned that it shouldn't show on iPhone X.

I already disabled the Emoji keyboard by setting the keyboard type to "ASCII Capable". Is there another setting to remove dictation?

[image]

Comment: What is your reason to restrict the user from use diction to fill a text field? This might negatively affect disabled users.

Comment: updated question, please check.

Comment: I understand that you don't want Emoji, but the dictation feature will just will the textfield with text, just like the user is typing it. So why do you want disallow this?

Comment: but, in iOS 11 its coming as separately, like outside of the keyboard. Thats I don't want make user misleads that if I show that Dictation icon.

Comment: You are saying you don't want to mislead an user, so you want to change the default behaviour of iOS. That is what the user expects on iOS 11 so don't change it.

Comment: I think, my requirement is customisation, like what I had described in above, if you are not understood, its okay. Anyway thanks for the reply.

Comment: Creat your own custom keyboard if you don’t like the default one. The mic button is just next the space bar normally. This is what a user expects.

Comment: in iOS 11, the mic button placement has been changed, its out side of the keyboard. Thats why I want to make it disable/hide.

Comment: Can you show a screenshots? Because on all my app it is still on the keyboard.

Comment: Have a look on this https://ibb.co/jwaOSm

Comment: Is this on the iPhone X because that is where it is on the iPhone X and that is where users on a iPhone X expect it to be.

Comment: That is iPhone X from simulator screen shot, thats why I mentioned in my query specifically iOS 11 version.

Comment: It is not there on any other iPhone expect the iPhone X, unless you create your own keyboard you can not remove it. And you should not, because user expect it to be there. It is not in any part of the screen where you should put UI elements any way. So just leave it.\

Comment: @AnilkumariOSdeveloper in settings, enabled dictation option there for on/off. OR you need to do by programmatically ?

Comment: Also you can't remove the keyboard switcher on the left. See my answer.

Comment: @NiravKotecha, I want to do it by programmatically.

Comment: @AnilkumariOSdeveloper you can not, nor should you. Since it is in all apps on the iPhone X and it is what user expect. Also if the user has more then one keyboard the keyboard switcher will be show in the left. Even if you disable Emoji. So what is the problem. It not space you can use in your app any way.

Answer (score 1):

We are talking about the mic symbol in lower right corner on an iPhone X.
You should **not** remove it since this is where users of an iPhone X are expecting it.

**Also you can not remove the keyboard switcher on the left.**
only if you use a custom view for the keyboard, but why?

[image]

As you can see on any other iPhone the mic key is still in the same position.
[image: keybord on none iPhone X]

Answer (score 0):

By changing type of keyboard you can discard things you don't want

```
textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress;
```

above one not exact solution but still that can give some idea regarding keyboard type

Hope this will help you

Comment: If I done this, Either one Emoji or Dictation icon coming. I want to hide them both.